# Service to automate the installation

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

Hi im having the following scenario and i need some guidelines to automate it .

1. I have 10 systems connected via network And each system having the console application [.exe] file.which i need to trigger to install the s/w , that is like a console application 
   and while installing i need to give 1 parameter in each step . The installation of s/w is about 10 steps .

I know we can done it by using RDP and manually install it but i need some service kind of thing to do it for me.We know it is easy to create a service in the remote machine but my question is how can i pass the parameters and install the application by simply triggering the service in each system having the s/w package

I know it is kind of insane question but kindly help me out

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is a true console application, reading from stdin, you can have all your responses in a text file, reponse per line and pipe it file to you application.

Ej. responses.txt

```
yes
no
192.168.1.1
c:\
```

And then, from batch / command line

```
type responses.txt | myApp.exe
```

If input from your application is not readed from stdin, some kind of automation tool could solve it.

Comment: it is not MSI application. it has no gui kind of things to install ill try this and let you know

Comment: if that doesn't solve it then `AutoIt` is an often used tool to script GUI responses.